# Merging two nested objects and concatenate arrays in side

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a build in method that merge two nested objects I make across [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
It is not working in my case because my nested object is `array`.

```
var obj1 = {
  "name": "Services",
  "category": "Services",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "Negative",
    "category": "Negative",
    "subCategory": [{           // only this part differ
      "name": "Expensive",  
      "val": 109,
      "subCategory": null
    }]
  }]
};  


var obj2 = {
  "name": "Services",
  "category": "Services",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "Negative",
    "category": "Negative",
    "subCategory": [{            // only this part differ
      "name": "Disorganized",
      "val": 25,
      "subCategory": null
    }]
  }]
};
```

It should merge like this

```
var result = {
  "name": "Services",
  "category": "Services",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "Negative",
    "category": "Negative",
    "subCategory": [{          //  array concatenation
      "name": "Disorganized",
      "val": 25,
      "subCategory": null
    }, {
      "name": "Expensive",
      "val": 109,
      "subCategory": null
    }]
  }]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just a proposal how to deal with same properties and same values and this special data structure, `'name'` and `'subCategory'`.

```
{
    "name": "Services",
    "subCategory": [
        {
            "name": "Negative", ...
            "subCategory": [
                {
                    "name": "Expensive", ...
                },
                {
                    "name": "Disorganized", ...
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This solution works with a recursion and adds the elements of `'subCategory'` if the name does not match.

```js
function fuse(target, source) {
    if (target.name === source.name) {
        source.subCategory.forEach(function (a) {
            target.subCategory.some(function (b) {
                return fuse(b, a);
            }) || (target.subCategory = target.subCategory.concat(source.subCategory));
        });
        return true;
    }
}

var obj1 = { "name": "Services", "category": "Services", "subCategory": [{ "name": "Negative", "category": "Negative", "subCategory": [{ "name": "Expensive", "val": 109, "subCategory": null }] }] },
    obj2 = { "name": "Services", "category": "Services", "subCategory": [{ "name": "Negative", "category": "Negative", "subCategory": [{ "name": "Disorganized", "val": 25, "subCategory": null }] }] };


fuse(obj1, obj2);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```